# Gemfile not found error when installing sqlite3 with bundler/inline

Tags: sqlite, rubygems, bundler

I want to create a Minitest example that uses ActiveRecord. I am installing required gems with `bundler/inline`:

```rb
# activerecord_bug_test.rb
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(true) do
  source "http://rubygems.org"
  gem "activerecord", "6.0.2.2"
  gem "sqlite3", "1.4.2"
end

# test code
```

When I run `bundle exec ruby activerecord_bug_test.rb` it fails with

```
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:197:in `handle_error': Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Bundler::InstallError)

    current directory: /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200324-11504-1f7q6pd.rb extconf.rb
/Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:32:in `build': /Users/hirurg103/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3/Gemfile not found (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
...
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I install `sqlite3` with

```sh
gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'
```

it goes without errors

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `bundle exec` prefix fixed the error for me:

```sh
ruby activerecord_bug_test.rb
```